# Is it better to make object's instance variable for connection static or non-static

Tags: java, jdbc, static, connection

I have a seperate class where I keep my connectivity.

```
public class ConnectionManager {
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/finance";    
private static String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   
private static String username = "root";   
private static String password = "";
private static Connection con;

public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {                
            System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection."); 
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {            
        System.out.println("Driver not found."); 
    }
    return con;
}
```

}

In the other "main" class I have:

```
public class TableWithBottomLine extends JPanel implements TableModelListener {

private Connection connection = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
private PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
private ResultSet resSet = null;
```

In the same "main" class in several places I call `connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();` and do some query related actions. Now I wonder, is it better to make these instance variables as static? For the sake of performance/security. Would be very happy if someone could share their insight.

Comment: IMO it's always bad to use static in this circumnstances. Use a connection pool instead (like [dbcp](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi))

Comment: Neither. It should be a local variable in association with a thread pool.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for your answer. I followed your advise. Two questions. 1. These extra lines in code when using local variables to do the job. I thought duplicate code isn't good? AND 2. Do I have to/is it better to lazily create the local connection variable by giving a null value before using it?

Answer (score 1):

If the `Connection` is `static` you can use only one instance to access the database.

Generally the best approach is to use a `ThreadLocal` Connection to have only one `Connection` per thread. This will allow to use multithreading without loosing performances, but use the same Connection for the same thread so you can handle `commit` (or `rollback`) operations only at the end of a certain number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to always have only one instance of connection in your program?

If so, your code does not do what you want, because each time you call `ConnectionManager.getConnection()` from somewhere, you create a new connection and assign it to the `con` static field.

You also loose a reference to your previous connection object, which looks like a resource leak.

You might want to try something like:

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/finance";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";

    private static final Connection CONNECTION = createConnection();

    private static Connection createConnection() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        return CONNECTION;
    }
}
```

Concerning your question, those instance variables in the client classes could be made final, in order to indicate that they are assigned only once. You could even get rid of those fields, and always call `getConnection()`, I think that performance impact will not be of any significance, and HotSpot will inline the calls anyway.

But if you're **not** trying to make a singleton connection, and use your `ConnectionManager` simply as a factory, then consider getting rid of `con` field, as it does not serve any purpose then. Then also making those client class fields static will make all the instances of your `TableWithBottomLine` share the same connection object - is this what you want?

Comment: I am not a Java Architect - just a mere beginner, trying to solve a problem and learn something. And that is why I cannot answer the question: do I want a single static connection or not. I think I understand the meaning of _static_ keyword. I was just wondering, what are the benefits/drawbacks of using it and what are business practices. From the responses I got by @BackSlash and others seems like the connection pool like dbcp is the way to go. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm also not a Java architect :) But my advice would be to start with the solution as simple as possible and don't worry about performance issues right from the beginning, 'cause you might be spending time optimizing wrong things.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to work with [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) (JDBC) or [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) (JPA).
One of the advantages: you can use a connection pool to get a pooled connection. This is good because creating a connection is quite expensive.

In Java EE environment you can just inject DataSource or EntityManager. The application server will manage the connection.

In Java SE environment you can use eg. the c3p0 to create DataSources with pooled connection support: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_c3p0

DataSource tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

JPA tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm